# How to quit the stdin/stdout program?

Tags: scala

I have the following code in Scala that I want to improve:

```
shouldContinue = true

while (shouldContinue) {
      val input = StdIn.readLine()
      if (input == ":q") {
        shouldContinue = false
        // do things here
      } else {
        System.exit(1)
      }
}
```

This program expects `:q` to quit. Is it possible to substitute `if (input == ":q")` but some built-in function that can detect `:q` or `:quit`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a tail-recursive function, which doesn't mutate like while loop. You can avoid using a var variable.

```
import scala.io.StdIn._
import scala.annotation.tailrec
@tailrec
def tailRecursiveCheck(shouldExit: Boolean): Unit = {
  if(shouldExit) System.exit(0)
  else {
    val s = readLine
    tailRecursiveCheck(s == ":q" || s == ":quit")
  }
}
tailRecursiveCheck(false)
```

Comment: What do you mean by saying "which doesn't mutate like while loop" ?

Comment: ShouldContinue = true (Avoiding var variables)